# How i do drop postgres database using python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have already tried this:

```
@api.multi
def get_database_list(self):
    self._cr.execute("SELECT (pg_stat_file('base/'||oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification, datname FROM pg_database")
    temp = []
    res=self._cr.fetchall()
    dt=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(15)
    for i in res:
        dt1 = i[0].replace(tzinfo=None)
        if(dt1 < dt):
            result=self.env['ir.config_parameter'].search([('key','=','database.to.skip')])
            test=result.value.split(',')
            if i[1] not in test:
                try:
                    self._cr.connection.set_isolation_level(0)
                    temp.append((i[1]))
                    self._cr.execute("drop database %s"%(i[1]))
                    self._cr.connection.set_isolation_level(1)
                except Exception ,e:
                    print e
    print temp
```

In this code only which database is droped that name is with underscore.
i can't drop which database that name in a dots are used for example demo.test .
how i can drop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double quote in above code i have already given in question.
`self._cr.execute("drop database \"%s\""%(i[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "quote_ident" to handle special characters.

Try:

```
 self._cr.execute("drop database quote_ident(%s)"%(i[1]))
```

Ref: [Link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE)

**Note:** You won't be able to drop DB if any user is connected via another session/connection.